# Проверка адреса на содержание его в зоне Яндекс Карт

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, typescript, yandex-maps-jsapi, yandex-geocoding-api

Я хочу реализовать следующий функционал, но не знаю нужного API в Yandex Maps. Запросы к тех. поддержке ограничиваются простым: Решить вопрос можно с помощью нашего API, но ответ ищите сами, мы ничего не знаем, вот ссылка на фулл-доку.

У меня есть данные зоны в виде JSON, импортированные с Конструктора Карт.
Я хочу реализовать собственную форму с тремя полями по типу:
Улица,
Дом,
Квартира/Офис

По запросу на кнопку, как я себе это представляю, должен происходить запрос к API Яндекс Карт, ответом на который бы служил ответ: Входит ли данный адрес в заданную мной зону, или же нет.

Но я не могу найти где можно достать координаты улицы и дома, а так же API для проверки входят ли эти координаты в заданный контейнер.

Для определения адреса использую API Яндекс Карт в виде подсказок для ввода корректного адреса.

Буду рад любой помощи, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

В песочнице Яндекса есть пример [Проверка адреса на попадание в зону доставки](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/delivery_zones)

Фактически это готовое решение вашей задачи. Остаётся немного скорректировать код на использование для ввода адреса не поисковой панели (она вам точно не подходит?), а собственной комбинации трёх полей.

Вам остаётся создать три поля, текст которых через запятые (и с городом вначале) будут отправляться в [геокодер](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/geocode.html), а дальше проверяться по примеру выше на попадание в зоны.